# Paypal IPN Integration

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

So I'm working on getting recurring payments to work on a website I'm working on (in PHP). I have IPN enabled on my Paypal account, and my button set up, etc.

When I click on the button on my website, it takes me to Paypal and I complete the process to signup. It then forwards me back to the correct url, with the big "auth" get variable. The transaction history is viewable in both my seller AND purchaser accounts.

The problem is with updating my database (mysql). I have tried several different IPN scripts and pieced together different ones from Google, Stackoverflow and various tutorials. None of the ones I've tried have been updating my DB which leads me to believe it's something with my approach that's going wrong.

Here's my ipn.php script:

```
<?php
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use:
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$notify_email =  "xxx"; //email address to which debug emails are sent to
$DB_Server = "xxx"; //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "xxx"; //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "xxx"; //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "xxx"; //your MySQL Database Name


if (!$fp) 
{
    // HTTP ERROR
} 
else 
{
mail($notify_email, "IPN Triggered 1", "IPN Triggered 1");  

fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

while (!feof($fp)) 
{
    //Already used this
    //$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

    //Using this to see if it sends response
    $res = stream_get_contents($fp, 1024);


    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
    {   
        mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED 1", "VERIFIED 1");

        //create MySQL connection
        $Connect = mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
        or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


        //select database
        $Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect)
        or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());


        $fecha = date("m")."/".date("d")."/".date("Y");
        $fecha = date("Y").date("m").date("d");

        //check if transaction ID has been processed before
        $checkquery = "SELECT txn_id FROM payments WHERE txn_id='".$txn_id."'";
        $sihay = mysql_query($checkquery) or die("Duplicate txn id check query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
        $nm = mysql_num_rows($sihay);

        if ($nm == 0)
        {
            //execute query
            if ($txn_type == "subscr_signup")
            {
                $strQuery = "INSERT INTO payments SET txn_id='".$txn_id."', user_id='$custom'";

                 $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die("Cart - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
            }
        // send an email in any case
         //echo "Verified";
            mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
        }
        else 
        {
            // send an email
            mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED DUPLICATED TRANSACTION", "$res\n $req \n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
        }
    }

    // if the IPN POST was 'INVALID'...do this
    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) 
    {
        // log for manual investigation
        mail($notify_email, "INVALID IPN", "$res\n $req");
    }
}

fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like any of your query variables are set anywhere. `$txn_id`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I do have my variables set right below where my DB variables are set, and right above the if statement. I took them out because it's quite a long list of variables that I didn't feel the need to include.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, disabling and then reenabling my IPN on Paypal seemed to fix the problem.